# How to maintain/generate tables in Hibernate for multi-user purpose?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I'm working on a project using Play Framework that requires me to create a multi-user application. I've a central panel where we add a certain workshop for a team. Thing is, I don't know if this is the best way, but I want to generate the tables like

team1_tablename
team1_secondtable..

Then when a certain request hits using the virtual host (e.x. http://teamawesome.workshop.com) I would need to maneuver the query to THAT certain table.

The problem is not generating the tables, but working with the models. All the workshops are going to have the same generic tables. In the model I would have to state the table, etc but then if this was PHP with doctrine I would have a template created them after creating the workshop team1, but in java even if I generate them I would have to compile them too which requires me to do more research.

My question is more Hibernate oriented before jumping the gun here and giving up on possible solutions. I'm all ears

I've thought of using NamedQueries, I don't know if I misread but I read in a hibernate book that you could query then add the result to a generic model so then I use that model to retain all my results...

If there are any doubts let me know, thanks (note this is not a multi database question, just using different sets of tables with unique prefixes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you could use one single set of tables, but have something like TEAM_ID as a foreign key in each table.

You would need one single TEAM table, where TEAM_ID will be the primary key. This will get migrated to tables and become part of foreign keys.

For instance, if you have a Player entity, having a collection of HighScores, then in the DB the Player table will have a TEAM_ID (foreign key from the Team table) and the HighScores table will have a composed foreign key (Player_id, Team_id) coming from the Player table..

**So, bottom line, I am suggesting a logical partitioning of your database rather then a physical one (as you've considered initially).**

Hope this makes sense, it definitely needs more thought, but if you think it's an interesting idea, I can think it through in more detail.

Comment: Right now, I'm structuring just the way you said :), it was initially an option that I dreadfully didn't want to take due to import/export complications, it gets more tricky than just saving team_tables. I know database management systems usually manage thousands of records in a table, the idea of teambased_tables seemed more viable for me because all the records were distributed appropriately. I'm still on time anyway to think through it and read more options available... I'll be happy to hear more :)

Comment: I think I'd need more information about your table structure, as otherwise I'd be discussing generic things and you'll have your particular issues in mind.. So, what's the highlevel structure of your db?

Comment: I know it might sound silly but due to the company I can't discuss many things, the team workshop is the closest thing I could match with the project I'm working in. I think all the answers here really helped me a lot, and I'm pretty sure now with what to do with my certain issues, pretty much the import/export team data will probably come for the next rolling release and it's not really priority. Cheers mate, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with Hibernate and another web framework, here is how I would handle it:

I would create a single set of tables for one team that would address all my needs.  Then I would:

- Using DB2: Create a schema for each team copying the set of tables into each schema.
- Using MySQL: Create a new Database for each copying the set of tables into each one.
  Note: A 'database' in MySQL is more like a schema in other databases. (Sorry I'd rather keep things too simple than miss the point)

Now you can set up a separate hibernate.cfg.xml file for each connection (this isn't exactly the best way but perhaps best to start because it's so easy).  Now you can specify the connection parameters... including the schema/db.  Now your entity table, lets say it's called "team" will use the "team" table where ever it is connected...

To get started very quickly, when a user logs on create a user object in their session.
The user object will have a Hibernate SessionFactory which will be used for all database requests built from the correct hibernate.cfg.xml file as determined by parsing the URL used in the login.

Once the above is working... There are some serious efficiency concerns to address.  That being that each logged on user is creating a SessionFactory... Maybe it isn't an issue if there isn't a lot of concurrent use but you probably want to look into Spring at that point and use a connection pool per team.  This way there is one Session factory per team and there is no major object creation when a user signs in.

The benefits of this solution is that it should be easier to create new sets of tables because each table set lives in it's own world.  There will only be one set of Entity Classes as opposed to the product of one for every team and table. The database schema stays rather simple not being complicated by adding team names and then the required constraints.  If the teams require data ownership and privacy it will be rather easy to move the database to a different location.

The down side is that if the model needs to be changed for a team it must be done for each team (as opposed to a single table set using teamName as a foreign key).

Comment: This wouldn't work nicely with play, because at the moment there is no support for multidb. So it would be the solution with multiple servers. Never the less it seams a cleaner solution for me too, excepts there are some common-tables for all teams.

Comment: Sad but true, just like niels say multidb support is kinda dead, I only wish that the play-framework team would adopt it and enhance it to be a more viable solution. But yea, it is a really easy and straight way to do it.

Comment: So play manages the hibernate session factory for you? Why not just use spring for DI then you're back in business.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using different tables for each team (despite what successful apps may use it) is honestly quite naïve, and has serious pitfalls when you take maintenance into account...
Just think what you will be forced to do if you discover you need a new table or even just an index... you'll end up needing to write DML scripts as templates and to use some (custom) software to run them on all the teams...

As mentioned in the other answers (Quaternion's and Octav's), I think you have two viable options:

1. Bring the "team" into your data model
2. Split the data in different databases/schemas

To choose the option that works best for you, you must decide if the "team" is really something you can partition your dataset into, or if it is really one more entity you want to bring into your datamodel.

You may have noticed that I'm using "splitting" here instead of "partitioning" - that's because the latter term is generally used by DBAs to indicate what we could call "sharding" - "splitting" is intended to be a stronger term.

Splitting is only viable if:

- entities in different partitions do not *ever* need to reference each other
- no query will *ever* need to access data from different partitions (this applies to queries used for reporting too)

As you might well see, splitting in this sense is not very attractive (maybe it could be ok now, but what when you find yourself wanting to add new features?), so **my advice is to go for the "the Team is an entity" solution**.

Also note that maintaining a set of databases/schemas is actually harder than maintaining a single (albeit maybe a bit more complex) database... again, think of what steps you should take to add an index in a production system...

The only downside of the single-databse solution manifests if you end up having multiple front-ends (maybe due to customizations for particular customers): changes to a shared database have the potential to affect all the applications using it, so you may need to coordinate upgrades to the different webapps to minimize risks (note, however, that in most cases you'll be able to change the database without breaking compatibility).

Comment: Yes, the application will have multiple front-ends, luckily I'm still on planning stage, thanks to this question I managed to gather more info on different scenarios, yes I also decided to go for that advice some hours ago because I'm making a big deal out of no hard facts whatsoever either. True, managing database updates will be MUCH easier and painless and setting modules for each team I can just establish set of permissions on what each team can use. The lack of multidb support in play-framework will make a living hell to manage in the long run too...

Answer (score 1):

After all it's a little bit frustrating to get no information just shoot into the dark. Nevertheless now I have start the work, I try to finish. 
I think you could do you job with following solution:

Wrote  a `PlayPlugin` and make sure you add to every request the team to the request `args`. Then you wrote your own `NamingStrategy`. In the `NamingStrategy` you could read the `request.args` and put the team into your table name. Depending on how you add it *Team*_ or *Team*. it will be your preferred solution or something with schema. It sounds that you have an db-schema so it would be probably the best solution to stay with this tables and don't migrate.

Please make the next time your request more abstract so that you can provide some information like how many tables, is team an entity and how much records a table has (max, avg, min). How stable is your table model? This are all questions which helps to give a clear recommendation with arguments.

Comment: Sorry for that, actually now that you mention that I'm a bit dumbfounded with that idea also sounds great, although I'm making the team a whole entity maybe in the next project I have I'll apply that since it seems like a really nice viable solution too. I really am thankful though, thanks again, I'll do my best to bring a clearer perspective of what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can try the module vhost, but it seems not very good maintained. But I think the idea to put the name of the team into the table name is really weired. Postgres and Oracle has schemas for that. So you use myTeam.myTable. But then you must do the persistence by your selves. 
Another approach would be different databases, but again you don't have good support by play. I would try this

- Run for each team a separate play-server, if you don't have to much teams.
- Put a reference to a Team-table for every model. Then you can use hibernate-filters or add it manually as additional parameter to each query. Of course this increase your performance. You can fix this issue with oracle partitions.

Comment: Not weird, well at least I kinda copied the idea from Wordpress Multi-User, I wonder if there is a different solution when I'm using Hibernate ORM

Comment: I still found it not very clever and guess it was database hack. So an important information is your database system on which you want to run your application.

Comment: Hmm, right now we are using MySQL. I'm going to check MySQL docs and hibernate mailing lists(if there's any) to see what I can gather =/. I think I should give Posgresql a visit... Thanks a lot though

Comment: Is the idea with the central Team-table an option for you?

Comment: It's kinda like required...  but like I said, I'm all ears to any options. Btw running separate play-servers might just become a nightmare in the long run which is why I just scratched it. I'm still checking on hibernate-filters, haven't had the time since I'm working on multiple projects right now =/

Comment: Well to make mutlidb runable in play you must do a lot. There was discussion about it in the google-group, so the idea with the central team-table seems the one which is the simplest to implement, but it depends who much teams and records your application will have. One server per team will be fine as long as you don't has hundreds of team handled by one hardware server. The advantage would be that each team has his own url. It's difficult to help with no detailed information, because there is no easy way. Each has drawbacks.